# Visual Studio Cordova - Not able to change input text fields

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-cordova

I have a Visual Studio Cordova application that I am building. I am using bootstrap and angular.  The application is pretty simple at the moment.  A few routes and views with text input fields.  When running in ripple things all work well, but when I run the Windows Simulator, I am unable to edit the data in the input fields.  I can clear the data by clicking the X or by highlighting the text and hitting delete, but I can't even get the focus in the input field.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to specify ng-csp to get around this issue.

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-csp>
```

See the angular documentation for [ngCsp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) for more details.